# What means donna in cryptography?

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, terminology

I've often see the word "donna" in some cryptography algorithm implementations.  So what it means?

Example: poly1305-donna, curve25519-donna and etc.

Comment: Reversely annoyed? Diffie-Hellman on NaCl?

Comment: I think only AGL knows.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com) without directly involving programming.

Comment: Very useful comment. It helps a lot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about cryptography. In case you haven't noticed by now, StackOverflow is for programming related questions only. Please use the sister sites for other questions and check if they are on topic over there.

Answer (score 1):

The poly1305-donna implementation was written by Andrew Moon, who states the following on naming his project [at GitHub](https://github.com/floodyberry/poly1305-donna):

> I borrowed the idea for these from Adam Langley's curve25519-donna,
>   hence the name.

And Adam Langley, who is the author of curve25519-donna, runs [a weblog about security and cryptography](https://www.imperialviolet.org) with his email address on (agl AT imperialviolet DOT org). Furthermore, he also has a [Twitter account](https://twitter.com/agl__).

So if you are really interested, maybe just drop him a line. I'd suppose, it simply is his wife's name. Or maybe it is related to the term *prima donna*, who is the leading female singer in the opera, to emphasize the algorithm's supremacy? But again, just guessing.